# Abnormal print out using paper-css and bootstrap flex design

Tags: html, css

I build a table using bootstrap //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css and apply the paper-css //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper-css/0.4.1/paper.css to print it on A4 size paper, I do set the @page as A4 size and body with 210mm width, don't know why the most right column not be printed but show on screen.

Here is the source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper-css/0.4.1/paper.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <style>
            @page { 
                size: A4
            }
            
            * { font-weight: normal; font-size: 12pt; }
            body { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 0px; }
            .align-left { text-align: left; }
            .align-right { text-align: right; }
            .align-center { text-align: center; }

            article {
                min-height: calc(100vh);
            }
            
            .container {
                display: flex;
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 1cm;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
                
            .column {
                flex: 1;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .row {
              flex: 1;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: row;
            }

                
            .cell {
                flex: 1;
            }


            @media print {
                html, body {
                    width: 210mm;
                    height: 297mm;
                }
            }

        </style>
    </head>
<body class="A4">
    <section class="sheet" style="padding: 10mm 15mm 0mm 15mm; margin-bottom: 10mm;">
        <article>
            <div class="container p-0 border border-secondary">
                <div class="container p-0">
                    <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 100%">
                        <div class="p-2 align-center border border-secondary cell" style="font-size: 1.5em;">FORM</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 80%">
                        <div class="container p-0 border-secondary">
                            <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 24.5%;">
                                <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell">Member Name</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 75.5%;">
                                <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell">Chinese：</div>
                                <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell">English：</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 24.5%;">
                                <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell">BOD：</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 75.5%;">
                                <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 100%;">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell" style="flex: 0 0 50%;">ID Number﹕</div>
                                        <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell" style="flex: 0 0 50%;">Gender﹕</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column" style="flex: 0 0 20%">
                        <div class="p-2 align-left border border-secondary cell" style="background-color: #c0c0c0;">
                            Internal Use
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <img class="footer"/>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The table has overflow and outside the window (so you have to scroll it in js)

Comment: How can I scroll it when print? It is repsonsive design and the container is 100%

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the issue can be fixed by replacing the bootstrap version with the latest version 5.1.

//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

[image]